# stuck with VAT percentages in c#

Tags: c#

so this is my question "Write a program that asks the user to enter the price without tax of one kilogram of tomatoes,the number of kilograms you want to buy and the VAT in percent units. The program must write the total price." and im fine up until the VAt part its confused me. i have got this so far

```
Int32 a;
Int32 b;
Int32 c;
Int32 d;

Console.WriteLine("please enter the price of one kilo of tomatoes without VAT.");
a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of kilos you want.");
b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("please enter the amount of VAT.");
c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

d = a * b;
```

Comment: *VAT* - Value Added Tax. For Instance if net price is 200, and VAT is 20% the price will be 200 + 20 % from 200 = 240; another issue: do you expect net price be *integer* value? Could it be, say, *1 dollar 15 cents*?

Comment: `d = a * b * ((c / 100) + 1);` should work. You might end up with floating point values though, so perhaps you should consider using `double` instead of `int` and then rounding the result.

Comment: @Oliver Nicholls: alas, `c / 100` will return `0` (if VAT < 100%, which is very common), if `c` is integer at t's now: `Int32 c;`

Answer (score 1):

All monetary amounts should be stored as decimals, not integers. If you are unclear about the difference, there are plenty of good reference sites and tutorials that will explain C# data types.

UK VAT is currently a nice round 20% so storing 20 as an integer would suffice. But the VAT rate was 17.5% not too long ago, so using a decimal variable is better.

Also, it's a really good idea to use meaningful variable names rather than single letters:

```
decimal price;
decimal quantity;
decimal vatRate;
decimal totalPrice;

Console.WriteLine("please enter the price of one kilo of tomatoes without VAT.");
price = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of kilos you want.");
quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Please enter the VAT rate. (Default = 20)");
decimal input;
if (Decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
{
    vatRate = input / 100;
}
else
{
    vatRate = 0.20M;
}

totalPrice = price * quantity * (1 + vatRate);
Console.WriteLine("Total price = {0}", totalPrice);
```

You should also look at rounding the output to the nearest penny.

Answer (score 0):

You should multiply net price with VAT percent and add that amount to net price. Then you should multiply it with kilogram value. However you should not use int for this kind of calculation because int does not keep floating point values. You should use decimal for any kind of financial calculations. In this way you can calculate exact result.

I think your code should be like that:

```
Int32 a;
    Int32 b;
    Int32 c;
    decimal d;

    Console.WriteLine("please enter the price of one kilo of tomatoes without VAT.");
    a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of kilos you want.");
    b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("please enter the amount of VAT.");
    c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    d = ((decimal)a * (1 + (decimal)c / 100)) * b;
    Console.WriteLine(d);
```

3 more recomendations. 
Variable names should be more descriptive. for example d can be result or vatIncludedAmount or something more easy to understand what d is.

a,b and c should be decimal because net price can be 1.15$ or you can buy 1.5 kilograms of tomatoes. And of course Convert.ToInt32 should be Convert.ToDecimal.

It would be nice if you check user input or at least use try catch blocks for convert lines because user can enter something different than a number. If user enters 2kg convert throws an exception for that.